# PhoneGap with Blackberry OS 10

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-10

I would like to know whether PhoneGap sdk supports Blackberry OS 10 build? I think it is .bar file, am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** Update **  At the time of this original answer, PhoneGap did NOT support BB10, however a lot has changed at you can now successfully build PhoneGap apps targeting BlackBerry 10.

I've re-written the PhoneGap Getting Started Guide (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20BlackBerry)

And a Knowledge Base article on the BlackBerry forums (http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Porting-your-existing-PhoneGap-application-to-BlackBerry-10/ta-p/2070503)

<strike>Phonegap doesn't support BlackBerry 10 yet.</strike>

Comment: Thank You chadtatro. Let me know one more thing, is there is any drawback/performance issue while porting/repacking an Android app to BB 10 .bar using repacking tool.

Comment: That's a good question, but I'm not the best person to answer porting questions :)  However, if you visit the BlackBerry support forums, we have some very knowledgeable folks who could give you a must better answer http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/bd-p/adt

Comment: Jan 2015: Phonegap no longer builds for Blackberry, Bada nor webOS. Cordova does via CLI (for BB10).

Answer (score 6):

PhoneGap 2.1.0 Fully supports Blackberry 10 (and Blackberry PlayBook) devices. It was released Sept 21st. Release Notes are located [Here](http://phonegap.com/blog/2012/09/21/phonegap-210/). In the build.properties file it supports both playbook and qnx (BB10) deployments. It has entries for simulators and physical devices.

Also, RIM's new HTML5 UI Toolkit [BBUI.js](https://github.com/blackberry/bbui.js) supports deploying BB10 styled apps on playbook devices.

Because of Cascades and the new UI/UX Guidlines, RIM is pushing for everyone who uses HTML5 to use a mobile API framework that supports the Cascade theme. 
Currently [Sencha Touch](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2011/03/sencha-touch/), [BBUI.js](https://github.com/blackberry/bbui.js) and [Jquery Mobile](https://github.com/blackberry/jQueryMobile-BB10-Theme) are the only ones that exist as of October 2012. Thats not to say you cant use Bootstrap, KendoUI or the plethra of others, just that your app wont meet the new BB10 UI/UX guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap does support BB10, but PhoneGap build does not yet.

Answer (score 1):

Until Build Phonegap catches up you might want to Try using https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/bpaa

You will need to have installed the Android SDK to your computer.

Then download the APK from Phonegap build and follow through the process as described on the webapps.blackberry.

*** If this is your first time getting BB signing keys the process could take up to 2 hrs for you to receive them (which are emailed to you once processed)***

If you have a valid APK (which you should if you successfully built it on Build.Phonegap) the process leads you through similar steps like Build.phonegap with keystore, P12 certificates etc.

Net result should be a downloadable BAR (Blackberry Archive) file.

I have done this only once... it wasn't a bad experience.

It would have been nice to see this bdsc site integrated to the Build.phonegap dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Its support, in the git https://github.com/blackberry/Cordova-Samples you can find samples and how work with BlackBerry 10 and phonegap