# Build phonegap app for blackberry using visual studio 2012 express in windows 8.1

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2012, blackberry, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am new in phonegap development and need to develop phone gap for Blackberry. Similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23960140/build-an-html5-web-app-to-work-in-blackberry-using-the-phonegap-build) (I don't understand the meaning in this link - "If you wish to build for other platforms, you will need to use Cordova locally on your machine.") .

But not solve my problem. I created a small app with Phonegap latest version via desktop version in visual studio 2012 express installed (OS: windows 8.1 ) and deploy on build.phonegap.com, but not get the blackberry option.

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583507/phonegap-with-blackberry-os-10) this article and other article too, but not any clue.

My question is currently is there any support in phone gap version to build and deploy for Blackberry phone (with visual studio) and which version of Blackberry phone support this.

If you have answer, then guide me step by step.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use PhoneGap with Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551711/how-to-use-phonegap-with-visual-studio)

Comment: http://www.profoundlogic.com/docs/display/PUI/Setting+up+Phonegap+for+Microsoft+Visual+Studio use this link also

Comment: sunil I am asking about blackberry version specific I have change my question please look into that.